# Como manter copias de arquivos em um repositório Git?

Tags: git

Eu mantenho esse repositório https://github.com/silash35/qpdftools-packages que contem arquivos binários de outro repositório. Ele foi criado para manter os arquivos necessários para construir pacotes. Atualmente ele só contem arquivos de construção de pacotes .deb, mas no futuro pretendo adicionar suporte para o Pacman (Arch Linux), Snap e talvez um .exe do Windows.

O Problema é que cada pasta contem uma copia do executável (O Binário). Por enquanto isso não é problema, pois se houver uma modificação no binário (Uma nova atualização por exemplo) eu posso manualmente mudar cada copia. Porem no futuro, quando o repositório dar suporte a vários gerenciadores de pacotes diferentes, vai ficar difícil manter tantas copias.

Tem alguma maneira de deixar os arquivos sincronizados automaticamente? Ou fazer o git entender que são o mesmo arquivo e que não precisa armazenar diferentes historias para eles?
Ou alguma outra solução, que não interfira na hora de fazer o dpkg-buildpackage ou similar não ocorra erros.

Answer (score -1):

Olá Silash35 tudo bem?

Você pode adicionar o arquivo .gitignore na raiz do seu projeto e inserir dentro dele os tipos de arquivos que o git deve ignorar. Por exemplo se você tiver um `.exe` que não queira que esteja no repositório adicione `*.exe` no seu gitignore.

Exemplo de um arquivo .gitignore:

```
#ignora tudo que não terminar com .txt (em todas as pastas)
!*.txt 

#ignora tudo que termina com .exe
*.exe
```

Após criar seu arquivo .gitignore será necessário remover estes arquivos do cache do git, então execute o seguinte comando:

- Remove os arquivos do cache
  `git rm -r --cached .`
- Faça um novo commit e observe que os arquivos serão excluídos da árvore
  `git commit -am "Meu Commit"`

Documentação: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar, Isso não resolve. Meu objetivo não é remover todos os binários e sim manter varias copias dele no repositório sincronizadas entre si.